# SQLite getting TOTAL from a list of columns?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to sum up the total value in my columns. I have 5 columns and i am able to get the total values 1 by 1 with:

```
import sqlite3
list2 = ['Food', 'Transport', 'Insurance', 'Installments', 'Others']

def expensedata():
    con = sqlite3.connect("expense.db")
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS expense (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,\
     food real, transport real, insurance real, installments real, others real)")
    con.commit()
    con.close()

expensedata()



con = sqlite3.connect("expense.db")
    c = con.cursor()
    c.execute("SELECT TOTAL(food) FROM expense")
    print(c.fetchall()[0])
    con.close()
```

I am able to get the total as `26.0` for this column.

But instead of repeating this code n times for n columns, i try:

```
con = sqlite3.connect("expense.db")
    c = con.cursor()
    for i in range(len(list2)):
        c.execute("SELECT TOTAL(?) FROM expense", (list2[i],))
        print(c.fetchall()[0])
    con.close()
```

but the output become `(0.0,) (0.0,) (0.0,) (0.0,) (0.0,)` instead.

How do i go around solving this problem? Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of a "TOTAL" aggregate function in SqlLite3. Standard SQL uses "SUM", is this something different about sqlite3?

Comment: @Researcher It's a variation on `sum()` that never returns null and always uses floating point: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc

Answer (score 1):

Just use string formatting:

```
c.execute("SELECT TOTAL(%s) FROM expense" % list2[i])
```

Comment: This will work fine for your home databases when you aren't worried about dirtbags doing SQL Injection. Regarding my question above is TOTAL an alias in Sqlite for SUM?

Comment: @Researcher The sum() and total() aggregate functions return sum of all non-NULL values in the group. If there are no non-NULL input rows then sum() returns NULL but total() returns 0.0. [SQL As Understood By SQLite - Aggregate Functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc)

Comment: Oh %s works in sqlite? I thought it was "?" and %s is for mysql...?

Comment: @LeongJunHao %s works in python, here is just a python's formatted string as a query.

Answer (score 1):

Instead, to select a *total* for all columns through a single SQL query - you may compose a query appropriately:

```
list2 = ['Food', 'Transport', 'Insurance', 'Installments', 'Others']
...
con = sqlite3.connect("expense.db")
c = con.cursor()

# just for testing
sql = ''' INSERT INTO expense(food, transport, insurance, installments, others)
             VALUES(?,?,?,?,?) '''

# sample records inserted into empty DB
c.execute(sql, range(0,5))
c.execute(sql, range(5,10))
c.execute(sql, range(10,15))

c.execute("SELECT {} FROM expense"
          .format(', '.join('TOTAL({})'.format(col.lower()) for col in list2)))
print(c.fetchall()[0])
con.close()
```

The output:

```
(15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 24.0, 27.0)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but i have a hard time making sense of and understanding: ```.format(', '.join('TOTAL({})'.format(col.lower()) for col in list2))```